# Join two sets of binary documents predicated on a condition in their respective properties

Tags: marklogic

Given two sets of binary documents (Residing in two different collections), I'd like to perform the equivalent of a left join, where the keys are part of the objects properties.

I'm doing something along these lines:

```
for $template in cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query(( 
                cts:collection-query("finances"), 
                cts:collection-query("http://marklogic.com/collections/dls/latest-version"),
                cts:collection-query("templates") ))),
$document in cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query(( 
                cts:collection-query("finances"), 
                cts:collection-query("http://marklogic.com/collections/dls/latest-version"),
                cts:collection-query("documents") )))
where $document/properties/templateId = $template/properties/objectId
and $document/properties/updatedDate < $template/properties/updatedDate

return $document
```

Which doesn't work one bit...

I would be very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Please explain your xpath expression. You state binary documents and then try to xpath into them. If you are trying to access the document properties fragment, explain that and give n example.

Comment: That's the crux of the problem. I can't use xpath to leverage these properties, so what's the alternative? My example was more of a proof-of-concept of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Please seed avid C's example as it is very effectively  But yes, you can xpath into property fragments. Do a search in the docs for 'property axis'

Answer (score 3):

MarkLogic allows you to store a property fragment at the same URI as a document fragment. You can do that with [`xdmp:document-set-property`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-set-property), establishing the templateId and objectId properties. You can then query those properties with [`cts:properties-fragment-query`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:properties-fragment-query). You can also examine the properties of a particular document using [`xdmp:document-properties`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-properties). Something like the code below, though you may have to fiddle with the XPath on the properties.

```
let $template-query:= 
  cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query("finances"),
    cts:collection-query("http://marklogic.com/collections/dls/latest-version"),
    cts:collection-query("templates")
  ))
let $doc-query := 
  cts:collection-query((
    cts:collection-query("finances"),
    cts:collection-query("http://marklogic.com/collections/dls/latest-version"),
    cts:collection-query("documents")
  ))

for $template-uri in cts:uris((), (), $template-query)
for $doc-uri in cts:uris((), (), $doc-query)
where xdmp:document-properties($doc-uri)/templateId = xdmp:document-properties(template-uri)/objectId
  and xdmp:document-properties($doc-uri)/updatedDate < xdmp:document-properties(template-uri)/updatedDate 
return fn:doc($doc-uri)
```

Edit: original version combined collections with OR instead of AND

Comment: I think the collection-queries are off. Multiple values to one query are evaluated with OR, e.g. the so-called shotgun-OR queries..

Comment: @grtjn -- you're right, as usual. Fixed, and thanks for pointing it out